# Python Pandas: group by is dropping columns

Tags: python, pandas

My problem is after group by I have left another columns than in functions and index. I would like to get all columns after groupby and index. How can I solve that?

The code:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/my.xlsx')
df2 = df.groupby('lokalny_id')['url'].agg(','.join)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

My dataframe:

```
    lokalny_id  url year    fid status
0   1234    73678_919317_M-33-35-D-a-1-4.tif    2022    123 w.
1   12  73678_919385_M-33-23-A-r-6-2.tif    2023    2   z.
2   1234    73678_919317_M-33-35-D-a-1-4.tif    2022    123 w.
3   13  73678_919385_M-33-23-O-k-2-3.tif    2020    3   z.
4   1234    73678_919317_M-33-35-D-a-1-4.tif    2022    123 w.
5   15  73678_919385_M-33-23-B-z-1-7.tif    2012    5   z.
6   17  73678_919385_M-33-23-D-c-2-9.tif    2013    6   o.
```

After group by:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8mGX.png)

Comment: In the second line, you specifically extracted `['url']` column after groupby to apply the agg function, that's why other columns are dropped.

Comment: What should I do to save another columns?

Comment: Add the columns to your groupby if unique per group or add them to your aggregration select [first, last, or something], or join the results of the groupby back to the original dataframe.

Comment: What is faster? My dataframe contains 15kk records.

Comment: If you are only aggregating the `url` column, then you should join it back to the original df after groupby and not touch other columns, but other columns are not aggregated, so the series after groupby will be having a different length than your original df. If you want to apply agg to all columns, then you should add them to your selection or simply remove `['url]'` to apply to all columns. We don't know what your expected result is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add all the columns that you do not want to aggregate to the index, and reset the index when done:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['lokalny_id', 'year', 'fid'])['url'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

It gives as expected:

```
   lokalny_id  year  fid                                                url
0          12  2023    2                   73678_919385_M-33-23-A-r-6-2.tif
1          13  2020    3                   73678_919385_M-33-23-O-k-2-3.tif
2          15  2012    5                   73678_919385_M-33-23-B-z-1-7.tif
3          17  2013    6                   73678_919385_M-33-23-D-c-2-9.tif
4        1234  2022  123  73678_919317_M-33-35-D-a-1-4.tif,73678_919317_...
```